# where in menuconfig is CONFIG_SMP located?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

when I do 'make menuconfig' and search for a config variable by typing `/PL011`, the search result shows where in the menu hierarchy the config variables are located and what the prompt value is. But in some cases like CONFIG_SMP, even if I type `/SMP`, it shows only the this.

```
Symbol: SMP [=y]                                                                                               
Type  : bool                                                                                                   
Defined at arch/arm64/Kconfig:304
```

But this doesn't help because I cannot find the menu for CONFIG_SMP and set the value as I want.  If I change the arch/arm64/Kconfig file directly, it causes build error.  Where is this CONFIG_SMP  in the menu hierarchy (linux-5.10.0) and how can I find this kind of menu item in general?

Comment: You can use the key `/` inside menuconfig to search configurations.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes I know it, but the result of `/SMP` is as shown in the question. No location information. I want to know how to get to the menu.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read so carefully. Go to that file `arch/arm64/Kconfig`, line 304, and then search backward for keyword `menu`. On some architectures/platforms it is just automatically selected (so look for other `SMP` or the dependencies)

Comment: "*I want to know how to get to the menu*" -- The **Kconfig** shows no menu prompt (in quotes) for that entry.  Presumably you could define it manually in a defconfig?

Comment: `make nconfig` is much better.

Comment: Hi all, I think @sawdust 's idea seems to be the answer. I tried `make nconfig` but some function keys conflics with my setting.

Comment: @sawdust please make your comment an answer so I can select it. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: `CONFIG_SMP` has been fixed to `=y` on arm64 since Linux v4.3 since nobody is building non-smp kernels nowadays: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4b3dc9679cf779339d9049800803dfc3c83433d1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how to get to the menu

The Kconfig definition for that config option has no menu prompt (in quotes).

```
config SMP
        def_bool y
```

So that's the reason why you couldn't (and will not) find (or be able to change) CONFIG_SMP in the menu.

---

My previous suggestion of "defining it manually in a defconfig" is not feasible.
Any prior definition of the config option (using `#CONFIG_SMP is not set` or `CONFIG_SMP=n`) in either a _defconfig file or the **.config** file was ineffective in overriding the default value specified by the Kconfig.  On exit from the 'make xxx_defconfig' or 'make menuconfig' procedure, the **.config** file would always contain `CONFIG_SMP=y`.

I'm inclined to believe that such configuration options are intended to be fixed for that arch, and are not intended to be changed.  Your unspecified "*build failures*" lend credence to this belief.

Perhaps you need to reevaluate why you want to change this config option from its default value.

Comment: Yes, I checked again and CONFIG_SMP becomes always y. (A colleage of mine suggested me to try CONFIG_SMP=n just to see if a problem goes away but we should have CONFIG_SMP=y so not worth a try)