How to disable CONFIG_KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK when building Linux kernel?
The kernel version is 6.9.0-rc4, the newest version for now.
The definition of the KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK config is as follows:
config KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK
    def_bool y
    depends on HAVE_RETHOOK
    depends on KRETPROBES
    select RETHOOK

This is the only occurance of KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK in all Kconfig files.
There is no statements like select KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK which can turn that config on automatically.
To disable the KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK config, I tried to manually edit the .config file as follows:
CONFIG_KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK=n

However, when I run make, the value of KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK is set to y automatically. why?

"The kernel version is 6.9.0-rc4, the newest version for now." - Not anymore. bootlin.com already has v6.9-rc5.  For a similar config symbol that defaults to y, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497113/where-in-menuconfig-is-config-smp-located

It is very strange, but as a workaround you could try to comment the whole block in order to leave it as UNSET.
As alternative you could try with:
make KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK=n <... other switches ...>

Let me know if it will work.

Still KRETPROBE_ON_RETHOOK is set to y automatically.

I edit my post to suggest you another possible way.

Still not work.

Sorry, but I can't help you anymore. I should put my hands on your PC. :)

Thanks a lot. You can check the comment above from sawdust. I found the answer from the question mentioned there. Seems there is no solution because def_bool in the Kconfig file forces the configration to y by design.
